# Xcode .cpp code getting error with lambda expression

Tags: c++, xcode, lambda

I am learning C++ these days, running code in Mac/XCode, and when I was doing the lambda expression today, I keep getting error for my D7_Listing7_12.cpp file

```
D7_Listing7_12.cpp:17:14: error: expected expression
             [](int Element) {cout << Element << " " << endl;});
             ^
D7_Listing7_12.cpp:33:11: error: expected expression
          [](int Num1, int Num2) {return (Num2 < Num1); } );
          ^
```

Here is how I define these two lambda inputs:

```
  for_each(dynArr.begin(), dynArr.end(),\
             [](int Element) {cout << Element << " ";});
```

and

```
sort (myNums.begin(), myNums.end(),
          [](int Num1, int Num2) {return (Num2 < Num1); } );
```

I've tried to search quite a lot answers online, some said it's an issue for mac Xcode clang since it's not using C++ 11, but some other people said most current Xcode shall running with C++11 as default. So I am confused now   :(

I've also run this in my terminal :

```
llvm-gcc --version
```

here is the result:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I am still pretty new with Xcode and C++, can someone help me out or give me some clue?

Thanks a lot

Kathy

Comment: What version of XCode are you running?

Comment: You can make sure you're using C++11 using these instructions (probably). Or at least it should look something like this. https://medium.com/@Rpessoa/how-to-code-in-c-14-with-xcode-8-2cb2eca9e5c8

Comment: Thanks @john for answering, my Xcode version is 9.2
I have went through the link and checked my project setup for C++, it's using std==gnu++14

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void DisplayNum(vector<int>& dynArr){
    for_each(dynArr.begin(), dynArr.end(),\
             [](int Element) {cout << Element << " ";});

    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> myNums;
    myNums.push_back(500);
    myNums.push_back(50);
    myNums.push_back(-10);
    myNums.push_back(1);

    DisplayNum(myNums);

    cout << "Sorting them in descending order :" << endl;
    sort (myNums.begin(), myNums.end(),
          [](int Num1, int Num2) {return (Num2 < Num1); } );

    DisplayNum(myNums);
    return 0;
}
```